# Prevent page load on refresh

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple html form which submits to the database on submit click.
It's working fine till here but after that when I refresh the page or page loads again,the values resubmit.How to rectify that?

Comment: Is it through `POST`? We need some code!!!

Comment: can we see what code u have done...?

Comment: Where do I post the code here??
Comments allow only 600 chars...??

Comment: you can edit your question and add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the form has been submitted, redirect to another page. Then refreshes will not matter.

See [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) on Wikipedia for details on this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

After u submit the page and data get stored in the database successfully reload the same page 
using

> `echo "<script>window.location='yourpagename.php'</script>";`